# Haskell main function doesn't print anything after it is run

Tags: haskell, program-entry-point

I have a simple module like this:

```
module Main where
import Semantic

main = do
    let result = linearize []
    print result
```

After I click on the .hs file, It only says that modules are loaded successfully and I can't see the final result. Is there anything I don't know?

Comment: You're probably in ghci. Can you type something in the window? If yes, try to type: `main`.

Comment: Yeah! it worked. is there any trick I can do so that everything runs automatic?

Comment: Are you using windows?  If so, then maybe you can change it to bind `*.hs` files to call `runhaskell` or `runghc` on them when you double-click them.  The default behavior is to open them in `ghci` when you click on them.

Comment: @bennofs For running a Haskell program in GHCi, `:main` is the "more correct" command as it simulates running the program in an actual environment with parameters and so on. `main` "just" evaluates the `main` function.

Comment: If you just want to experiment with your `linearize` function, you could also open `Semantic.hs` in ghci and type `linearize []` directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How exactly are you running your code?  Normally, you'd use `runhaskell` to compile and run, or you can do it in two steps with `ghc --make`.  Since it's saying that all modules are loaded successfully, I'm guessing it's getting opened in `ghci`, which is the interactive haskell shell, which is often used for testing and experimentation.  Try running your file with `runhaskell`.

Comment: @ye9ane: Note that it's possible to see the final result in `ghci`. You just type `main` and `<Enter>`.